# Querying sums of grouped consecutive rows in PostgreSQL 9

Tags: postgresql, window-functions

I have data about people traveling in different countries like this:

```
country | begintimestamp      | distance    

Germany | 2015-01-01 00:00:00 | 100
Germany | 2015-01-01 01:12:13 | 30
France  | 2015-01-01 02:13:14 | 40
France  | 2015-01-01 03:14:15 | 20
Spain   | 2015-01-01 04:15:16 | 10
France  | 2015-01-01 05:16:17 | 30
France  | 2015-01-01 05:17:18 | 5
Germany | 2015-01-01 06:18:19 | 3
```

What I need is to be able to receive a result like this - the `distance` of consecutive rows summed with the earliest `begintimestamp`:

```
country | begintimestamp      | distance

Germany | 2015-01-01 00:00:00 | 130  // 100+30, the distance of two first rows summed.
France  | 2015-01-01 02:13:14 | 60   // 40+20
Spain   | 2015-01-01 04:15:16 | 10   // 
France  | 2015-01-01 05:16:17 | 35   // 30+5
Germany | 2015-01-01 06:18:19 | 3
```

I've tried to play around with PG window functions but have not been able to come up with anything that would lead me closer to the result.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
select min(country) as country,
       min(begintimestamp) as first_begin_ts, 
       sum(distance) as distance
from (
  select t1.*, 
         sum(group_flag) over (order by begintimestamp) as grp
  from (
      select *,
             case
                when lag(country) over (order by begintimestamp) = country then null
                else 1
              end as group_flag
      from travel
  ) t1
) t2
group by grp
order by first_begin_ts;
```

The inner most query (alias `t1`) creates a number each time the country changes). The second level query (alias `t2`) then does a running sum on those flags, which essentially gives each consecutive set of countries a different number. The outer most query then groups by that number and sums the distance. The `min(country)` is necessary to make the `group by` operator happy, but as all rows with the same `grp` have the same country anyway, it doesn't matter.

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/fe341/1