# Calculating the percentage change from the previous row

Tags: postgresql, window-functions

I just entered the world of window functions. I have a similar problem to solve as in [this question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/90987/1192).

I have this table:

[image: table]

The last column `(%Grown)` is given by:

```
-(1 - price of row 2 / price of row 1) * 100
```

All the information I have found so far was related to sums, avg for all rows. I don't know how to bound two rows so I can calculate the percentage.

How do I translate this into SQL?

Comment: What column should be used for the ordering of rows?

Answer (score 11):

The best way I think would be to use the `LAG()` or `LEAD()` functions:

```
SELECT *, 
       - 100.0 * (1 - LEAD(Price) OVER (ORDER BY t.Id) / Price) AS Grown
FROM table_name AS t
ORDER BY t.Id ;
```

With `LEAD(Price) OVER (ORDER BY t.Id)` you have access to the next `Price` when the rows are ordered by `Id`. It's not clear what the order should be. Based on the data in the question, you may want `(ORDER BY Price DESC)`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Actually, the table is a query and I'm trying to calculate the price variation from one purchase date to another. (say you buy some bricks in 01.01.2015 with 5$, on 05.01.2015 with 10$ and on 10.01.2015 with 10$) I think it may work with a function as well, but I'm so stuck...

Comment: It doesn't matter if it's a base table or a query result. Just replace `table_name` with your query `(SELECT ....)` and play with the `(ORDER BY ...) ` inside the `OVER`.

Answer (score -1):

You can use Common Table expression,

```
WITH Data as (select  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY applicable_date) as RowId, date, qty, price, [value] from tbl
)
SELECT 
CurrentRow.date, CurrentRow.qty, CurrentRow.price, CurrentRow.[value], 'Your calculation here for Growth'
FROM Data as CurrentRow
LEFT OUTER JOIN Data as NextRow ON NextRow.RowId = CurrentRow.RowId + 1
WHERE NextSlice.RowId IS NOT NULL
```

I Hope it helps.

Comment: `[value]` is an invalid identifier (`[` or `]` or not allowed in an SQL identifier)

Comment: in postgres you can use reserved words with " "

Comment: Thank you, Mouliin. However, I am lost. What's NextSlice?

Comment: Sorry, It should be NextRow and CurrentRow. I only used [value] because it was in the original table structure.

Comment: There was a `Value` in the question, not a `[Value]`